# What should I change in my conditional statements to produce the correct triangle classification?

Tags: c, ubuntu-16.04

I want to let the user input any three values that would indicate the dimensions of the sides of a triangle. The conditional statements in the code will classify whether the sides will make up a triangle. If it does make a triangle, it will display if the triangle is scalene or right or both.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(void)  
{  
//Declare the variables for the sides of the triangle  
float a; //first side  
float b; //second side  
float c; //third side  
float scalene;  //check for scalene  
float right; //check for right  
float ans; //check if sides are a triangle  
float rep; //check if user wants to continue after the sides are not a 
triangle  

//Get user inputs for the sides of the triangle  
printf("Input the first side of the triangle: ");  
scanf("%f", &a);  

printf("Input the side for the second side of the triangle: ");  
scanf("%f", &b);  

printf("Input the last side of the triangle: ");  
scanf("%f", &c);  

//Conditional statements:  

//Determine if the sides make up a triangle  
>if ((a+b)<c || (b+c)<a || (a+c)<b)  
>{  
ans=0;  
}  
else  
{  
ans=1;  
}  
//If the sides make up a triangle, is the triangle scalene? If scalene, 
//each side is unique to the others  
for (ans=1;ans<3;ans++)  
{  
if (a==b || a==c || b==c)  
{  
scalene=0;  
>}  
else  
{  
scalene=1;  
}  
//if the sides make a right triangle, they would satisfy one of the 
//following Pythagorean theorem  
if ((a*a+b*b)==(c*c) || (b*b+c*c)==(a*a) || (a*a+c*c)==(b*b))  
{  
right=1;  
}  
else  
{  
right=0;  
}  

for (ans=0;ans<2;ans++)  
>{  
printf("Your sides do not make a triangle. Enter 1 if you would like to 
input new values. Enter any other number to finish: \n");  
scanf("%f", &rep);  
}  
if (rep==1)  //repeat the steps again  
{  
printf("Input the first side of the triangle: ");  
scanf("%f", &a);  

printf("Input the side for the second side of the triangle: ");  
scanf("%f", &b);  

printf("Input the last side of the triangle: ");  
scanf("%f", &c);  
>}  
else  
{  
printf("Thank you for using Triangle Check. Have a nice day!");  
return 0;  
}  
}  

//Display the results to the user  
if (scalene==1 && right==1)  
{  
printf("Your triangle is both a scalene and right!");  
return 0;  
}  
else if (scalene==0 && right==1)  
{  
printf("Based on your sides, it is a right triangle!");  
return 0;  
}  
else if (scalene==1 && right==0)  
{  
printf("Based on your sides, it is a right triangle!");  
return 0;  
}  
else  
{  
printf("Your triangle is neither right or scalene.");  
return 0;  
}  


 return 0;  
 }
```

If I enter 3, 4, 5 for the sides and I should get that the triangle makes up a right triangle.

But I get that the sides do not make up a triangle.

Comment: Putting all information into html  comments, so that they are invisible, is a really unhelpful idea. It already got you downvotes.

Comment: Hurry to take the [tour] or your lack of understanding will get you nowhere near a good answer.

Comment: "What is the actual result you get?" Show it, then explain about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is confused and therefore you are confused. Get rid of `ans` — you don’t need it. Structure your program to *immediately* respond to stuff. Get rid of loops you don’t need. (This program does not need any loops at all.)

For example, when checking for *is it a triangle*, check, and if it fails, *quit*.

```
if ((a+b)<c || (b+c)<a || (a+c)<b)
{
  puts( "Alas, your sides to not make a triangle." );
  return 1;
}
```

It is okay to make the user try again by running the program again. (Yes, you *could* do it so that it asks again, but that adds complexity that *do not need* right now. Focus on the task given you.)

If the code continues past this spot, then you know it must be a triangle. The next trick is to test for *types* of triangles. For example:

```
if (a != b && b != c)
{
  puts( "The triangle is SCALENE." );
}
```

And continue with the next test.

Flaggy programs (yours uses `ans`, `scalene`, `right`, etc to do nothing more than report a truth value) do not help you. Avoid being tricky.

Good luck!